# If $ \sin\phi_1 + \cos\phi_1 \sin\theta_1=\sin\phi_2+\cos\phi_2\sin\theta_2 $, does it necessarily mean $\phi_1 = \phi_2$ and $\theta_1 = \theta_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra

**Background:**
In phased array beamforming, the phase of an antenna is given by:
$$
\operatorname{phase}(x_m, y_m, \theta,\phi) = x_m\cdot \sin\phi + y_m\cdot \cos\phi \sin\theta
$$

where $x_m, y_m$ are the x and y-coordinates, and $\theta$, $\phi$ are the azimuth and elevation of a beam.

**Motivation**: Can an antenna have the same phase for 2 beams in different directions?

**Question**: Does the below equation necessarily mean that $\phi_1 = \phi_2$ and $\theta_1 = \theta_2$
$$
x_m\cdot \sin\phi_1 + y_m\cdot \cos\phi_1 \sin\theta_1 = x_m\cdot \sin\phi_2 + y_m\cdot \cos\phi_2 \sin\theta_2
$$

**My attempts**: Starting with a simple case where $x_m \ne 0$ and $y_m = 0$ (and vice-versa), we prove $\phi_1 = \phi_2$ and $\theta_1 = \theta_2$

Extending to slightly more complex case where $x_m = y_m$, I get the below equation for which I am unable to prove that $\phi_1 = \phi_2$ and $\theta_1 = \theta_2$:
$$
\sin\phi_1 + \cos\phi_1 \sin\theta_1 = \sin\phi_2 +\cos\phi_2 \sin\theta_2
$$

I tried rearranging the terms, squaring them, dividing by different trigonometric terms, but no progress has been made.

How can I prove/disprove (either mathematically or through a counterexample) the above equation?

Comment: Are $\phi_i, \theta_i$ restricted to real angles? There are certainly a large number of non trivial solutions to this over the complex plane. But since you have a physics/engineering application perhaps these don’t count.

Comment: Only in rare circumstances will one equation simultaneously fix two variables.

Comment: There is no continuous one-to-one function from a nonempty open subset of $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal, yes, the angles must be real.

Comment: A really simple counterexample is just $\phi_{2} = \pi -\phi_{1}$, $\theta_{2} = -\theta_{1}$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$\newcommand\th\theta\newcommand\p\partial$Let $f(\phi,\th):=\sin\phi+\cos\phi\,\sin\th$. Your question is whether $f(\phi_1,\th_1)=f(\phi_2,\th_2)$ implies $\phi_1=\phi_2$ and $\th_1=\th_2$.

The answer to this question is: Of course not.

Indeed, take any $\phi_1$ and $\th_1$ such that $\cos\phi_1\ne0$ and  $\cos\th_1\ne0$. Then the partial derivative $\p_\th f(\phi_1,\th_1)$ of $f(\phi,\th)$ with respect to $\th$ at $(\phi,\th)=(\phi_1,\th_1)$ is $\cos\phi_1\,\cos\th_1\ne0$.

So, by the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem), for each $\th_2$ close enough to $\th_1$ (but not necessarily equal to $\th_1$) there is some $\phi_2$ such that $f(\phi_1,\th_1)=f(\phi_2,\th_2)$. $\quad\Box$

---

Shown below is the set of all points $(\phi_2,\th_2)\in(0,\pi)\times(0,2\pi)$ such that $f(\phi_2,\th_2)=f(\phi_1,\th_1)$ given the point $P:=(\phi_1,\th_1)=(\pi/6,\pi/4)$. This (infinite) set of points is the union of the two blue closed curves, and the black point lying on one of the two closed curves is $P$:
[image]

---

You can also explicitly describe the solutions $(\phi_2,\th_2)$ of the equation
$$\sin\phi_1+\cos\phi_1\,\sin\th_1=\sin\phi_2+\cos\phi_2\,\sin\th_2 \tag{1}\label{1}$$
given $(\phi_1,\th_1)$. In particular, fixing any $(\phi_1,\th_1)$ such that $\cos\phi_1\ne0$ and $-1<\sin\th_1<1$, for all $\phi_2$ close enough to $\phi_1$ you can rewrite \eqref{1} as
$$\sin\th_2=h(\phi_2):=h_{\phi_1,\th_1}(\phi_2)
:=\frac{\sin\phi_1+\cos\phi_1\,\sin\th_1-\sin\phi_2}{\cos\phi_2}, \tag{2}\label{2}$$
so as $h(\phi_2)$ be close enough to $\sin\th_1$ and hence in the interval $[-1,1]$. Then you can solve \eqref{2} and thus \eqref{1} for $\th_2$:
$$\th_2=\arcsin\frac{\sin\phi_1+\cos\phi_1\,\sin\th_1-\sin\phi_2}{\cos\phi_2},$$
for all $\phi_2$ close enough to $\phi_1$.